# Gigya: Retrieving number of facebook likes for an article or component

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, gigya

There are thousands of articles in our site and we would like to know the number of facebook likes for the top stories in the site. We have a control that lists the top stories of the site and we want to use gigya to retrieve the number of likes for each of the top story. In our site we are using a gigya share bar for facebook likes and other social media sharing. So we are not doing the facebook likes through url, we are passing useraction info to the share bar. Now how do I retrieve the number of facebook likes for a specific article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See socialize.getProviderShareCounts - 
http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/010_Socialize/socialize.getProviderShareCounts

Comment: thanks for the answer, I figured it out...We are in fact using the URL to do the likes. Thanks!